# Cannot publish web job with 15 min reoccurrance using Azure SDK 2.4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

When I try to publish a console app as a web job (reoccurring every 15 minutes) to a web site being hosted on "Standard" instances (x2), I get the following error from the ms build target:

> S:...\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.0\tools\webjobs.console.targets(80,5):
>   Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule:
>   Conflict: The provided job has a recurrence that is outside of quota
>   for free subscriptions. The minimum recurrence for the job collection
>   is '01:00:00'. To increase quota please upgrade to standard or premium
>   plan.

I don't think this is correct, since the web sites are operating in a standard plan. Is this a bug in the tooling, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheduling part of a scheduled WebJob is done using Azure Scheduler which is a separate resource in Azure and has it's own pricing (and free/paid offering).

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/scheduler/

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I forgot about that part.

Comment: Mind you though that raising the service level on your Azure Scheduler from Free to Standard pushes all your Azure Websites to the Standard level as well. You can't create any free Azure Website instances anymore after this.

Comment: @Koen that is simply not true, Azure scheduler does not affect Azure Websites.

Comment: @AmitApple, strange since that is what is happening here. All my free Azure Website instances got boosted to Standard service level and whenever I try to create a new Azure Website on Free or move the Standard back to Free, it throws an error.

Comment: @Koen this shouldn't happen, start a thread in the azure websites forum [here]( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: Got it sorted out now by following @AmitApple his advise. Turned out I had everything configured in one service plan. In the new Azure portal you can define multiple service plans which define the service level for all services contained within at once.